# How to get access to dropped values in pandas?

Tags: pandas, drop

My datasets hava two columns with values. In order to calculate top 1% of the data in each column, I used `quantile` method. After that,
I dropped the values which are higher than top 1% in my datasets by `drop` method.
Now, I want to get my dropped values. How can I access the dropped values in a separate column?

```
features = ['HYG_FT01', 'HYG_PU12_PW_PV']
for features in df:
    new_df = df[[features]].quantile(q=.99, axis=0, numeric_only=True).iloc[0]
    df.drop(df[df[features] > new_df].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: is this your expected output?https://i.imgur.com/Vl8ScYJ.png

Comment: mostly, yeap, i can reorganize the rows. how did you do that?

Comment: _I dropped the values which are higher than top 1%_ - The _top 1%_ consist of the highest values; there are no values that are _higher than_ the highest values.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code hope it's help, if you want me to specify let me know in the comments

```
features = ['HYG_FT01', 'HYG_PU12_PW_PV']
for features in df:
    new_df = df[[features]].quantile(q=.9, axis=0, numeric_only=True).iloc[0]
    df[features+ '_droped'] = np.where(df[features] <= new_df,None,df[features])
    df[features] = np.where(df[features] > new_df,None,df[features])
    
df
```

output:
[image]